# statement is not execute using Execute Immediate in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Following statement is executed in normal execution but when use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` no result return.

```
select distinct 
    FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.FeedbackQuestionId as id,
    FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.FeedbackQuestionId  
from FEEDBACKQUESTIONS 
left join LANGUAGES on FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.LanguageId = LANGUAGES.LanguageId  
where 
    1=1 
    and FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.CrdBy = 1 
order by 
    FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.FeedbackQuestionId desc 
    OFFSET 10 * (1 - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Please post your execute immediate statement.

Comment: DECLARE
     p_CrdBy number := 1;
     begin
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select distinct FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.FeedbackQuestionId as id,FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.FeedbackQuestionId  from FEEDBACKQUESTIONS left join LANGUAGES on FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.LanguageId = LANGUAGES.LanguageId   where 1=1  and FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.CrdBy = 1 order by FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.FeedbackQuestionId desc OFFSET 10 * (1 - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY'
;
--using p_CrdBy;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_CrdBy);
end;

Comment: @WinjitNiraj You should edit your question with the additional data not post it as comment...

Comment: You are getting any error? or getting `0` rows?

Comment: I am getting 0 rows

Answer (score 0):

From [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-statement.html#GUID-C3245A95-B85B-4280-A01F-12307B108DC8)

> If dynamic_sql_statement is a SELECT statement, and you omit both into_clause and bulk_collect_into_clause, then execute_immediate_statement never executes.

You have use `SELECT INTO` clause and assign the values to some variable if you want to see the results of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` select values. If your `select` statement returns just one row then you can use the below procedure.

```
DECLARE P_CRDBY NUMBER := 1; 
V_ID VARCHAR2(20);
V_QID VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT DISTINCT FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.FEEDBACKQUESTIONID AS ID,
                   FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.FEEDBACKQUESTIONID FROM FEEDBACKQUESTIONS 
                   LEFT JOIN LANGUAGES ON FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.LANGUAGEID = LANGUAGES.LANGUAGEID 
                   WHERE 1=1 AND FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.CRDBY = 1 
                   ORDER BY FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.FEEDBACKQUESTIONID DESC 
                   OFFSET 10 * (1 - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY' 
                   INTO V_ID,V_QID ; 
                   --USING P_CRDBY; DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(P_CRDBY); 
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID=' || V_ID ||', ID2=' || V_QID);
 END;
```

For multiple rows you can use `FOR LOOP CURSOR` to loop through your result set.

```
DECLARE P_CRDBY NUMBER := 1; 
V_ID VARCHAR2(20);
V_QID VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN 
FOR MYROW IN (SELECT DISTINCT FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.FEEDBACKQUESTIONID AS ID,
                   FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.FEEDBACKQUESTIONID AS ID2 FROM FEEDBACKQUESTIONS 
                   LEFT JOIN LANGUAGES ON FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.LANGUAGEID = LANGUAGES.LANGUAGEID 
                   WHERE 1=1 AND FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.CRDBY = 1 
                   ORDER BY FEEDBACKQUESTIONS.FEEDBACKQUESTIONID DESC 
                   OFFSET 10 * (1 - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY) 
 --USING P_CRDBY; DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(P_CRDBY); 
LOOP                
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID=' || MYROW.ID||', ID2=' || MYROW.ID2);
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: It will definitely throw : `ORA-01422: fetch returns more than requested number of rows`

Comment: @Tejash, I agree. I didnt think about that. Then `Cursor` should be used.  i will edit the answer. Thanks

Comment: if i want to return result set from above query then What I can do?..please suggest me

Comment: It is possible make table format result  ID | ID2 ...like sql return result set

Comment: @WinjitNiraj, Not sure what you mean? Table format like?

Comment: In simple execution like 'select * from mytable' gives table format data like that .

Comment: @WinjitNiraj, then you can execute the select statement itself. What is the use of this anonymous block? :) BTW may I know what are you trying to do after selecting?